# Is there any listener on Android SearchView to notify if SearchView is expanded and ready to take input?

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I want to show some default suggestions in SearchView when User hasn't typed anything. 
I am setting my custom suggestion adapter manually using matrix cursor. I tried setting adapter in onFocusChange and onClickListner but suggestions get hidden behind a keyboard, apparently suggestions are loading earlier than keyboard.
I did not find any listener which tells me that searchview is completely loaded with keyboard in the view.
Help me in finding the right solution or any workaround. I have tried a workaround postDelayed but it's not smooth experience.

I have this code inside onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    final MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchview_in_menu, menu);
    this.menu=menu;
    basketProductCount = ShoppinglistDataSource.get(getContext()).getProductCountToOrder();
    if(basketProductCount>0 && menu!=null){
        this.activateBasket();
    }

    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        int searchButtonId = mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
        ImageView searchButton = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchButtonId);
        if(searchButton!=null)
            searchButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);



        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchProductActivity.class)));
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setIconified(true);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search from 4000+ products");
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                Log.d("SEARCH_VIEW_DEBUG","Inside onQueryTextSubmit for query: "+s);
                mSearchView.clearFocus();
                mSearchView.setIconified(true);
                //return false to let the SearchView perform the default action
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                query = query.toLowerCase().trim();
                Log.d("Query changed to ",query);
                if (query.length() > 1) {
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("query",query);
                    if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(1)!=null)
                        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, b, suggestionLoaderCallback);
                    else
                        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, b, suggestionLoaderCallback);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new SearchView.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
                Log.d("DEBUGGIN", "onFocusChange");
                if(!queryTextFocused) {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                        mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
                        mSearchView.clearFocus();
                    }
                } else {
                    /**This is doing the trick, but not smooth experience**/
              /**also suggestions may get behind the keyboard if keyboard takes time to pop up**/
                    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                                mSearchView.onActionViewExpanded();
                                Log.d("DEBUGGIN", "Inside expand");
                                if (mSearchView.getQuery().length() == 0) {

                                    Log.d("DEBUGGIN", "getting default suggestions");
                                    sug.clear();
                                    sug.add("Personal Care");
                                    sug.add("Oil");
                                    sug.add("Spices");
                                    sug.add("Breakfast");
                                    sug.add("Snacks");
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                                        String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", "text"};
                                        Object[] temp = new Object[]{0, "default"};
                                        final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);
                                        int i = 0;
                                        for (i = 0; i < sug.size(); i++) {
                                            if (!sug.get(i).equals("")) {
                                                temp[0] = i;
                                                temp[1] = sug.get(i);
                                                cursor.addRow(temp);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        Log.d("Initial categories", sug.toString());
                                        mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new CustomSuggestionAdapter(ListAll.this, cursor, sug));
                                        mSearchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        mSearchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int i) {
                                                Log.d("SEARCH_VIEW_DEBUG", "Inside onSuggestionSelect");



                                                return false;
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int i) {
                                                Log.d("SEARCH_VIEW_DEBUG", "Inside onSuggestionClick");
                                                MatrixCursor cursor = (MatrixCursor) mSearchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getItem(i);
                                                String suggest1 = cursor.getString(cursor
                                                        .getColumnIndex("text"));
                                                Log.d("Clicked Item", suggest1);
                                                mSearchView.setQuery(suggest1, true);
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }, 600);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                /**This never gets called**/
                Log.d("DEBUGGIN", "Inside onMenuItemActionExpand");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                /**This never gets called**/
                Log.d("DEBUGGIN", "Inside onMenuItemActionCollapse");
                return true;
            }
        });
    } else {
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                /**This never gets called**/
                Log.d("DEBUGGIN", "Inside MenuItemCompat onMenuItemActionExpand");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                /**This never gets called**/
                Log.d("DEBUGGIN", "Inside MenuItemCompat onMenuItemActionCollapse");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    //return true onCreateOptionsMenu
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can set an expand/collapse listener on the `MenuItem` like this:

```
menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

This listener was introduced with API level 14, so for backwards compatibility you have to use the v4 support library. If you do then you have to set the expand/collapse listener like this:

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(this.searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this. onMenuItemActionExpand is not getting called.  I have posted code in question.

Comment: If you are calling it in `onCreateOptionsMenu` then use code like `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setOnActionExpandListener()`

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Neither onMenuItemActionExpand nor onMenuItemActionCollapse is getting called at all. Tried on emulator with API 24.

Answer (score 9):

the questioner wants to know how to know when the searchview is expanded.  just do this with your searchview (assuming its standalone but you can get a reference to it from menu item if needed):

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //search is expanded
                    }
                });
```

here is for closed situation:

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onClose() {
// searchview closed
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        vwSearch = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_main_search).getActionView();
        vwSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                 //Do something on Submit
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                 //Do something on change
                return true;
            }


        });

        vwSearch.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                //Do something on collapse Searchview
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in AndroidManifest.xml along with your activity for example name of your activity is activity1.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app1.activity1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_one"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

instead of "adjustPan" you might use "adjustResize"